# Can't solve an equasion with sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I tried to solve a simple equasion for x whice i wanted to print 0

Code:

```
import sympy as sp
a, b, c, d, x = sp.symbols('a b c d x')

f = sp.sympify( 'a/b' )
f1 = sp.sympify( 'c/d' )
f2 = sp.sympify( 'a/b - c/d' )

eq = sp.Eq(f,5)
eq1 = sp.Eq(f1,5)
eq2 = sp.Eq(f2, x)

ans = sp.solve((eq, eq1, eq2), (x))
print(ans)
```

Output:
`{x: (a*d - b*c)/(b*d)}`

Answer (score 0):

You are solving three equations for a single unknown. If you want some of the symbols to be eliminated from the solution for `x` then you should add them as unknowns as well:

```
In [17]: eq
Out[17]: 
a    
─ = 5
b    

In [18]: eq1
Out[18]: 
c    
─ = 5
d    

In [19]: eq2
Out[19]: 
a   c    
─ - ─ = x
b   d    

In [20]: solve([eq, eq1, eq2], [x])
Out[20]: 
⎧   a⋅d - b⋅c⎫
⎨x: ─────────⎬
⎩      b⋅d   ⎭
```

That is a valid solution but involves the other symbols. Let's ask solve to solve for three symbols so that they all get eliminated from the solution:

```
In [22]: solve([eq, eq1, eq2], [x, a, c])
Out[22]: {a: 5⋅b, c: 5⋅d, x: 0}
```

You only want the solution for `x` so:

```
In [23]: sol = solve([eq, eq1, eq2], [x, a, c])

In [24]: sol
Out[24]: {a: 5⋅b, c: 5⋅d, x: 0}

In [25]: sol[x]
Out[25]: 0
```